# How to call operations on JMS temporary queue from JBOSS CLI

Tags: java, jboss, jms, hornetq, jms-topic

I am trying to call operations such as `listDeliveringMessages()` on a temporary Queue (say `fe517553-6c53-42d6-8aaa-d8ea154fd8b0`), created by a jms.Topic in JBoss 6.4.0.GA EAP / 7.2.x. I need to do that from JBoss CLI.

I got close to do that by running:

```
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/jms-queue=fe517553-6c53-42d6-8aaa-d8ea154fd8b0
```

But the JBoss CLI says that the queue is not found. Yet, If i approach this from JVisualVM and check the MBeans, I can run the operations visually (which is not what I am looking for!):

[image: queue]

And when selecting that I can have a list of all attributes:

[image]

What command should I run to get the same attributes and call operations from JBoss CLI?

Comment: What version of JBoss AS are you using?

Comment: Hi Justin, v6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queues used for topic subscriptions can be found in `runtime-queue`.  For example, if you created a subscriber on a topic called `myTopic` you could run this command:

```
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/jms-topic=myTopic/:list-all-subscriptions
```

That would give you information on all the current subscribers including the name of the subscription queue, e.g.:

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [{
        "durable" => false,
        "queueName" => "6257c1d9-9039-4e76-a4cd-857de77f13a8",
        "messageCount" => 0,
        "deliveringCount" => 0,
        "consumers" => [{
            "creationTime" => 1535727397857L,
            "consumerID" => 0,
            "browseOnly" => false,
            "connectionID" => "397639080",
            "sessionID" => "0fb5712d-ad2e-11e8-94a8-45dabcb25ee3"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Then you can take the name of the subscription queue and look it up with a command like the following:

```
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/runtime-queue=6257c1d9-9039-4e76-a4cd-857de77f13a8:read-resource(include-runtime=true)
```

That would tell you all the properties of the queue, e.g.:

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "consumer-count" => 1,
        "dead-letter-address" => "jms.queue.DLQ",
        "delivering-count" => 0,
        "durable" => false,
        "expiry-address" => "jms.queue.ExpiryQueue",
        "filter" => undefined,
        "id" => 52L,
        "message-count" => 0L,
        "messages-added" => 0L,
        "paused" => false,
        "queue-address" => "jms.topic.myTopic",
        "scheduled-count" => 0L,
        "temporary" => true
    }
}
```

However, the `list-all-delivering-messages` operation doesn't appear to be supported for this queue.